# Where can I get mozilla lightning v.0.9 release for mac?

Tags: mac, thunderbird, firefox, lightning

I have tried to search for an older version of lightning for mac but couldn't find any. Anybody have an ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tired [this one](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addons/versions/2313#version-0.9) ? Be careful of old versions.